# Husky Quaternion Rotation w/ Odometry

Tags: husky, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone help me understand what is going on here?

I was following this quaternion tutorial and trying to apply it to a clearpath Husky A-200 : http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Quaternion+and+Rotation+Primer

I understand quaternions to be

> [x y z w]T = [sin(a/2)*nx,
> sin(a/2)*ny, sin(a/2)*nx, cos(a/2)]T

, where a is the angle of rotation and [nx ny nz] describe the vector to rotate about.  So, if I input

> (a=180, [nx ny nz] = [0,0,1])
>
> quaternion = [0, 0, 1, 0]

and the Husky should rotate 180 degrees.  However, it consistently rotates 90 degrees.  This is all relative to the 'odom' frame.  After its first rotation I would expect an input of

> (a=0, [nx ny nz] = [0,0,1])

> quaternion = [0, 0, 0, 1]

to return the Husky to its starting orientation in the odom frame; however, this causes it to complete it's 180.

Can someone please explain what is happening?  What quaternion do I need to do a 180 degree rotation?

We are using following commands to run the gazebo and navigation packages:

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch
roslaunch husky_navigation odom_navigation_demo.launch
```

Commands are published to the /move_base_simple/goal topic relative to the odom frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132601/husky-quaternion-rotation-w/-odometry/) by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<strike>Shouldn't your goal pose be relative to the fixed frame (which might be `map`)?</strike>

**Edit**: A of course the `odom` frame is fixed, sorry. Haven't used the nav stack in a while.

A few things to try out is sending the robot to do translation as well as rotation and manually inspecting the cmd_vel topic to see what the planner/controller is trying to do. You can also visualize the planned path as well as the goal pose in rviz [1].

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on 2014-02-24**:
/move_base_simple/goal only takes input in the 'odom' frame - it sends an error otherwise (The goal pose passed to this planner must be in the odom frame.  It is instead in the map frame).

In any case I understand the odom frame to be a fixed frame according to http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

**Comment by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on 2014-02-25**:
RViz produces the expected outputs.  I think this is wheel slip causing the odometry to be incorrect.  Tested this on a real Husky and it produced the same 90-degree turn with 180-degree input. Kudos to an accurate gazebo simulation, and thanks for your help

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-03-07**:
This is correct (-Clearpath)